# Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to attack a simple feedforward neural network with attakcs implemented in `cleverhans.attacks`. The network is a very basic network implemented in `tensorflow` implementing the abstract class `cleverhans.model.Model`:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from cleverhans.model import Model


class TFModel(Model):
# A basic 2 layer NN.

def __init__(self):
    self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3), name='x')
    self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2), name='y')
    
    self.w1 = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[1., 2.], [1., 2.], [1., 2.]], name='w1')
    self.b1 = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1., 2.], name='b1')
    self.dense1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(self.x, self.w1), self.b1, name='dense1')
    self.out1 = tf.nn.softmax(self.dense1, name='out1')
    
    self.w2 = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[1., 2.], [1., 2.]], name='w2')
    self.b2 = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1., 2.], name='b2')
    self.dense2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(self.out1, self.w2), self.b2, name='dense2')  # should be called 'logits'
    self.out2 = tf.nn.softmax(self.dense2, name='out2')
    
    self.outputs = {'layer1': self.out1,
                    'logits': self.dense2,
                    'softmax': self.out2}

def get_layer_names(self):
    """
    :return: a list of names for the layers that can be exposed by this
    model abstraction.
    """
    return list(self.outputs.keys())

def fprop(self, x):
    """
    Exposes all the layers of the model returned by get_layer_names.
    :param x: A symbolic representation (Tensor) of the network input
    :return: A dictionary mapping layer names to the symbolic
             representation of their output.
    """
    return self.outputs
```

Attack implemented with `FastGradientMethod` works well as shown in the following:

```html
model = TFModel()
sess = tf.Session()
from cleverhans.attacks import FastGradientMethod
fgsm_params = {'eps': 0.3,
               'clip_min': 0.,
               'clip_max': 1.}
fgsm = FastGradientMethod(model, sess=sess)
adv_x = fgsm.generate(model.x, **fgsm_params)
```

But attack with `BasicIterativeMethod` does not work:

```html
from cleverhans.attacks import BasicIterativeMethod
bim_params = {'eps_iter': 0.01,
              'nb_iter': 100,
              'clip_min': 0.,
              'clip_max': 1.}
bim = BasicIterativeMethod(model, sess=sess)
adv_x = bim.generate(model.x, **bim_params)
```

Here is the full error message:

```html
rror                                Traceback (most recent call last)~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    509                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 510                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    511           except TypeError as err:
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
   1103     if ret is None:
-> 1104       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1105 
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    234   _ = as_ref
--> 235   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    236 
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    213       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
--> 214           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
    215   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    419     if values is None:
--> 420       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
    421     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
ValueError: None values not supported.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    523               observed = ops.internal_convert_to_tensor(
--> 524                   values, as_ref=input_arg.is_ref).dtype.name
    525             except ValueError as err:
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
   1103     if ret is None:
-> 1104       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1105 
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    234   _ = as_ref
--> 235   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    236 
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    213       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
--> 214           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
    215   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    419     if values is None:
--> 420       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
    421     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
ValueError: None values not supported.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-7-8ab4a61acce1> in <module>()
      8 print('hello')
      9 
---> 10 adv_x = bim.generate(model.x, **bim_params)
c:\users\mjafarnia\src\cleverhans\cleverhans\attacks.py in generate(self, x, **kwargs)
    400                                      sess=self.sess)
    401             # Compute this step's perturbation
--> 402             adv_x = FGM.generate(x + eta, **fgm_params)
    403 
    404             # Clipping perturbation according to clip_min and clip_max
c:\users\mjafarnia\src\cleverhans\cleverhans\attacks.py in generate(self, x, **kwargs)
    284                    ord=self.ord, clip_min=self.clip_min,
    285                    clip_max=self.clip_max,
--> 286                    targeted=(self.y_target is not None))
    287 
    288     def parse_params(self, eps=0.3, ord=np.inf, y=None, y_target=None,
c:\users\mjafarnia\src\cleverhans\cleverhans\attacks_tf.py in fgm(x, preds, y, eps, ord, clip_min, clip_max, targeted)
     65     if ord == np.inf:
     66         # Take sign of gradient
---> 67         normalized_grad = tf.sign(grad)
     68         # The following line should not change the numerical results.
     69         # It applies only because `normalized_grad` is the output of
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in sign(x, name)
    451           indices=x.indices, values=x_sign, dense_shape=x.dense_shape)
    452     else:
--> 453       return gen_math_ops.sign(x, name=name)
    454 
    455 
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py in sign(x, name)
   6874   if _ctx is None or not _ctx._eager_context.is_eager:
   6875     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
-> 6876         "Sign", x=x, name=name)
   6877     _result = _op.outputs[:]
   6878     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    526               raise ValueError(
    527                   "Tried to convert '%s' to a tensor and failed. Error: %s" %
--> 528                   (input_name, err))
    529             prefix = ("Input '%s' of '%s' Op has type %s that does not match" %
    530                       (input_name, op_type_name, observed))
ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic iterative method (BIM) applies the fast gradient sign method (FGSM) multiple times (100 times with the parameters that you have specified). Each step of the BIM applies the FGSM on the outcome of the previous step of the BIM. Therefore, your model object needs to have a method `fprop` that returns the output of the model for any input tensor passed as an argument. The current class you have implemented always returns the output of the model on the same placeholder `self.x`. You will have to use scopes to define a `fprop` method that can take an arbitrary tensor `x` and return the output of the model on that input. You can find an example of a simple model implementation `ModelBasicCNN` that does that in the tutorials folder: https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans_tutorials/tutorial_models.py